# Python: grayscale image to RGB image with provided palette

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb, grayscale

I am stuck with a problem.

I want to convert many greyscale images to `RGBA` with my dictionary palette where `greyScale value = (r,g,b)` (adding transparency `0` where the pixel is `0`).

I wrote some code but it takes `~0.3sec` to end one transformation.
Is there some faster way to get better performance?

Thanks <3

[image: My code]

[image: My Dict:]

Comment: Rather than adding a link to an image to your code and dictionary, it's better to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance depends on your image resolution. But you can use Numpy like this for the case.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def grayscale_to_rgba_optimized(image, palette):
    """Converts a grayscale image to RGBA using a dictionary palette efficiently.

    Args:
        image: A 2D grayscale image array.
        palette: A dictionary mapping grayscale values to RGBA tuples.

    Returns:
        A 3D RGBA image array.
    """

    lookup_array = np.array([palette.get(i, (0, 0, 0, 0)) for i in range(256)])
    rgba_image = lookup_array[image]
    return rgba_image

colors = {
    -35: (243, 243, 243),
    -30: (207, 207, 207),
    ......
    90: (77, 77, 77)
}

gray_img = Image.open('Your_Image_Path.png').convert('L')
gray_array = np.array(gray_img)

rgba_image = grayscale_to_rgba_optimized(gray_array, colors)

# Save the result as a PNG image (transparency will be preserved)
result_image = Image.fromarray(rgba_image, 'RGBA')
result_image.save("output_image.png")
```